# simplexml_load_file not working "php_network_getaddresses: failed: Name or service not known"

Tags: php, simplexml

I started getting these warnings just recently, im not sure why, nor do i know how to fix it. What confuses me more, it was working before, i started working on another class and now i starting getting this error...

im using linux fedora & apache for the webserver.

> Warning: simplexml_load_file()
>   [function.simplexml-load-file]:
>   php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo
>   failed: Name or service not known in
>   GetImagesFlickr.php
>   on line 17
>
> Warning:
>   simplexml_load_file(http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.search&api_key=9eb9f5e5fb72d6d2fed06cf4e64ba9bb&media=photos&per_page=50&text=fgdc)
>   [function.simplexml-load-file]: failed
>   to open stream:
>   php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo
>   failed: Name or service not known in
>   GetImagesFlickr.php
>   on line 17
>
> Warning: simplexml_load_file()
>   [function.simplexml-load-file]: I/O
>   warning : failed to load external
>   entity
>   "http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.search&api_key=9eb9f5e5fb72d6d2fed06cf4e64ba9bb&media=photos&per_page=50&text=fgdc"
>   in
>   /var/www/html/yahoo/GetImagesFlickr.php
>   on line 17

```
<?php
class GetImagesFlickr
{
    const API_KEY = "***"; // Flickr api key
    const MAX_RESULTS_RETURNED = 50; // Max results returned in search

    private $url; // Flickr webservice url

    public function __construct () 
    {
        $this->url = "http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.search&api_key=".self::API_KEY."&media=photos&per_page=".self::MAX_RESULTS_RETURNED;
    }

    public function getImages ($search_term)
    {
        // Perform search and store xml data
        $xml_data = simplexml_load_file("{$this->url}&text={$search_term}");

        $search_results = array();

        // Go through xml data and store to array
        foreach ($xml_data->photos->photo as $current_photo)
        {
            $id = $current_photo['id'];
                        $title = $current_photo['title'];
            $farm = $current_photo['farm'];
            $secret = $current_photo['secret'];
            $server = $current_photo['server'];
            $url = "http://farm{$farm}.static.flickr.com/{$server}/{$id}_{$secret}.jpg";

            $complete_photo = array (
                'id'     => $id,
                                'title'  => $title,
                'farm'   => $farm,
                'secret' => $secret,
                'server' => $server,
                'url'    => $url
            );

            $search_results[] = $complete_photo;
        }

        return $search_results;
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a network/DNS problem, not a PHP problem. Seems your machine cannot resolve the IP of `api.flickr.com`.

"su" to your web server user and try to resolve the name there, i.e.

```
$ sudo bash
  # get root
$ su - apache
  # we're the apache user now
$ ping api.flickr.com
```

Comment: how do i fix this?.. .i can access api.flickr.com in firefox.

Comment: i can ping it..

ping api.flickr.com
PING www.flickr.vip.mud.yahoo.com (68.142.214.24) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from www.flickr.vip.mud.yahoo.com (68.142.214.24): icmp_req=1 ttl=51 time=242 ms
64 bytes from www.flickr.vip.mud.yahoo.com (68.142.214.24): icmp_req=2 ttl=51 time=242 ms

Comment: But can your PHP/apache process resolve the IP? Try to use the IP itself instead of api.flickr.com in your request.

Comment: hi there.. yeah it worked when i used the ip address instead of api.flickr.com... could you explain why this is so. I would prefer to use the domain rather than the ip.. thx :)

Comment: because your apache/php process cannot resolve the IP as I said. Maybe they cannot access `/etc/rescolv.conf` to find out the DNS server.

Comment: this is the contents of my rescolv.conf: # Generated by NetworkManager
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
should i add anything

Comment: thx buddy.. i changed the permissions on /etc/rescolv.conf and restarted apache and it did the trick.