# PHP SoapCLient, Soap call giving an error in Drupal

Tags: soap, soap-client, php

I am getting the following error, when I try making a SOAP call.

> Warning: SoapClient::__doRequest() [soapclient.--dorequest]: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known in

and the error

> HTTP-Could not connect to host

Things that I have ensured :

- allow_url_fopen : is enabled.
- The WSDL is being accessed. The server is not down.
- I have set the SOAP time out to 15 seconds.

Comment: according to the error message your DNS resolving is not working for the host you're trying to reach. typo in in the hostname ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The IP of the host you are connecting to cannot be resolved. See my answer in

> [simplexml_load_file not working "php_network_getaddresses: failed: Name or service not known"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6561769/simplexml-load-file-not-working-php-network-getaddresses-failed-name-or-servic/6561783#6561783)

for what to do.

Comment: Accepting this as it is the closest answer. It didnt work though:(